# Setting near mode for depth cam in Kinect using OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni

I have been unable to find out how i can set the Kinect depth mode to near (40-300mm) using OpenNi. I am programming in C++ and would like to keep using the OpenNi libraries for retreiving the depth data, however i cannot find any property of setting that i should use for changing modes.

Answer (score 0):

I too wanted to do the same thing. I googled up a bit and found following

[libfreenect](https://github.com/dxli/libfreenect/tree/nearMode) which is a fork from [OpenKinect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect)

This fork with the branch "nearMode" provides capability to work in NEAR_MODE. This is a compile time solution only. I plan to compile and use it.